# How to hide and show a <div> onclick when there's already an action for click?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, show-hide, blogger

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.

I'd like to hide the `<div id="disqus_thread">`, and reveal it when I click on the link "*commenting*", when comments load (The link is at the bottom of my article: "*commentaires*", on [my blog](http://www.julienlussiez.com/2013/01/le-repos-du-fou_21.html)).

I have a link with `onclick`, but I can't add another action.

How could I manage to have both actions trigger on clicks?

**CSS:**

```
#disqus_thread {display:none; margin-top: -40px; background: #fff;
background: #fff;
padding:20px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

I tried to hide the div using css, but I don't know how to reveal it then.

---

**HTML:**

```
<li class='commenting'>
  <span class=''>
    <a class='' expr:href='data:post.addCommentUrl' onclick='$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});$.getScript(&quot;http://julienlussiez.disqus.com/embed.js&quot;);$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});$(&quot;#disqus_loader&quot;).remove();' title='Laisser un commentaire'>Commentaires</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

There's an `onclick` function, but I can't add anything.
Is it incorrect, or rather, badly written?

---

**Script:**

```
<script>
    function load_disqus()
    {
      var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
      dsq.src = "http://julienlussiez.disqus.com/embed.js";
      (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
      var ldr = document.getElementById('disqus_loader');
      ldr.parentNode.removeChild(ldr);
    }
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    $.Ajaxify.pageChange(function() {

        var disqus_shortname = 'julienlussiez';
        // required: replace example with your forum shortname

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();});
</script>
<a name="bottom"></a>
```

This script loads comments from disqus without interuption. It's good because I have a music player on my blog.

Comment: It's typically bad form to write so much code in the html onClick.  It's better to bind it using jQuery's on method which it appears that you are using

Comment: Thanks! So what should I do? I don't really understand what I'm doing, I need some help...
Should I write the code somewhere else? Is it possible to have two actions for a single onclick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can assign only one click function to the element.

To make it work, try to put your functions stacked into a new function and then assign it to the `onclick` through javascript:

HTML:

```
<div id='test'></div>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');

div.onclick = function () { alert("some function") };

// hides the div
div.onclick = stackFunction(div.onclick, function () { 
    div.style.display = "none"; 
});

function stackFunction(last, f) {
    return function () { last(); f(); };
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKdLh/2/)

Comment: It works but I don't know how to implemante a function that hide a <div>.

Comment: I have added to the above fiddle, it shows you how to hide the div on the second function http://jsfiddle.net/eKdLh/2/

Comment: Yes, it works but I'd like to do the opposite in fact. I'd like to show a <div> onclick: 
#disqus_thread {margin-top: -40px; background: #fff;
background: #fff;
padding:20px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;} --> #disqus_thread {display:none;margin-top: -40px; background: #fff;
background: #fff;
padding:20px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;}

Comment: @user2182652 I'd go ahead and say lante has already answered your question. You wanted 2 actions on a single link, and you've got it. He's brought you 99% of the way there, I feel you might be able to manage the rest yourself.

Comment: Yes that's right, it's pretty good. Maybe it's enough, I'm going to try different things.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark answer if you feel it appropriate.

Comment: Don't forget you can add as many handlers to a click event as you want. Rather than element.onclick = function; Just use element.addEventListener('click', function, false); You could assign many, many functions to be executed when the element is clicked. You also have the opposite, element.removeEventListener('click', function,false) - This will allow you to remove a single handler without interfering with any of the others that have been attached.